# Multiple Nested Transformations cause Spark Dataframe to hang

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a deeply nested Dataframe and am trying to apply transformations to existing nested columns. This is how I am going about doing it:

```
    val output = df.withColumn("top_level", col("top_level")
  .withField("going.further.down.value", hashWithSaltUdf(col("top_level.going.further.down.value"))))
```

This works fine when I apply one or a few transformations like in the example above. But as soon as I start chaining/applying 5 or more transformations to other nested fields within the same dataframe then all of a sudden the dataframe will hang when I try and perform any methods on it (like df.show(), df.select...etc). When I say "hang" I mean the application will be blocked at the line where I am invoking a df.show(), df.select...etc.

Does anyone know why this may be? I am running the job locally.

Comment: Did you try to cache intermediate results? repartition may also help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been an bug with Spark that has since been fixed with Spark 3.4.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28090